# Function that finds duplicate names by inputting a name list

Tags: python, arrays, input

guys I'm a beginner who is new to Python.
I want to create mthod which find duplicate name in list. So, I created it but it doesn't work the way I want.

This is my code

```
def find_same_name(name) :
    result = set()
    for i in range(0 , len(name) - 1) :
        for j in range(i + 1, len(name)) :
            if name[i] == name[j] :
                result.add(name[i])
    return result
name = input("Please Write Name ")
print(name)
#print(type(name))
print(find_same_name(name))
```

And this is my result

Please Write Name Tom Jerry Mike Tom Kim
Tom Jerry Mike Tom Kim
{'T', 'o', ' ', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'm'}

Why it print as type character? I don't know what is wrong. Would you guys pleas help me?

Comment: What do you exactly expect here : do you want to persist somehow the input names or does it have to work only once ?

Comment: You need to pass a list into find_same_name(name). But you are passing a string. You can call find_same_name like print(find_same_name(name.split(" "))).

Comment: `.split()` is what you probably want.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are iterating over each letter in the list, not every name. To iterate over every name you can use the .split() function which splits a string into a list based on (by default) the spaces.

```
def find_same_name(name) :
    allnames = name.split()
    result = set()
    for i in range(0 , len(allnames) - 1) :
        for j in range(i + 1, len(name)) :
            if allnames[i] == allnames[j] :
                result.add(name[i])
    return result

name = input("Please Write Names: ")
print(name)
print(find_same_name(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Please Write Name ").split(' ')
```

It is a simple mistake you made.
You are using the name as a string instead of list of names. Use 'split' to make the given names into list and apply the function

Answer (score 0):

`name = input("Please Write Name ")`

This line assign `name` as a string. So when you do `name[i]` in the function, it returns a single letter.

To solve that, assign `name` as a list:
`name = input("Please Write Name ").split()`

The `split()` method transforms the string with seperate names into a list that records all seperate name, so you can use `name[i]` to get the names.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.

your problem is, that you want to hand over a list of names to your method, but your are currently hand over a single string "Tom Jerry Mike Tom Kim Tom Jerry Mike Tom Kim". If you do this, python will access the single letters withing the string and not the words. I guess, you want to split the input on spaces, which can be done by:

```
name = input("Please Write Name ")
name_list = name.split(" ")
print(name_list)
print(type(name))  # will be list now, not str
print(find_same_name(name_list))
```